# How to use scriptVariables in hive (AWS Data Pipeline)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-data-pipeline

We can pass script variables into AWS data pipeline hiveactivity using the following construct :

```
"scriptVariable" : [
    "param1=value1",
    "param2=value2"
  ]
```

How do we access these variables in the hive script? I have been trying to use them in a select statement without any success :

```
Select ${hiveconf:param1}, dummytable.col1,...
from dummytable where dummytable.id = 1;
```

My knowledge of hive is limited. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just write ${param1}.

You can test it by starting hive with -d.

> hive -d param1=2014-06-20

```
select * from something where dt='${param1}';
```

Comment: This was a huge help! The AWS documentation can be a little vague at times.